# How do I compare numbers with a null check in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

What is the most elegant what of comparing numbers in freemarker?

```
<#if (variable = 2) ></#if>
```

This will not include a null check?

If I do this

```
 <#if (variable! = 2) ></#if>
```

Then freemarker will complain about different types.

I ended up doing this

```
<#if (variable!?html = "2") ></#if>
```

But I guess this is not the way of doing it? How do I compare numbers with a null check in freemarker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you want to happen if the variable is null? If you want then false:

```
<#if variable?? && variable == 2 ></#if>
```

If you want to assume 0:

```
<#if variable!0 == 2 ></#if>
```

Notes: `=` also works, but is a bad practice, as the expression can be confused with named parameter assignment. The `()` is redundant; it's not like in Java. `?html` meant to be used escaping `<` and such, but worse, you trigger localized formatting there that can spoil the comparison. So if you ever want to do something like that, use `?c` (**c**omputer formatting) instead.